# matlab: cut out certain rows from data into new matrix

Tags: matlab

I have few raw_data file similar as below...**each.dat file has different number of rows**...However, in each raw_data file, the first 2 rows and last 2 rows will be moved into angle_data.dat file...so that after programming through matlab code, each raw_data file will create 2 new files: one is angle_data file and another is final_data file...(final_data file is the remaining data from raw_data file)...

raw_data1.dat

A B 0.0 1.2222 3.1111

C U 0.0 2.333 12.999

G T 3.4 2.3 5.666

R P 2.5 44.3 6.777

R Q 8.222 5.999 0.344

After programming through matlab code, result as below:

angle_data1.dat

A B 0.0 1.2222 3.1111

C U 0.0 2.333 12.999

R P 2.5 44.3 6.777

R Q 8.222 5.999 0.344

final_data1.dat

G T 3.4 2.3 5.666

Comment: Please click on "edit" and format it according to the guidelines in the sidebar to the right. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more info. I could do it for you, but it's better if you learn to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work:

```
angleData=rawData(1:2;end-1:end);
finalData=rawData(3:end-2);
```

I might have swapped rows and columns there, but that's the idea.  I don't have a copy of matlab on this machine to test it.

EDIT: just in case:

```
angleData=rawData(:,1:2;:,end-1:end);
finalData=rawData(:,3:end-2);
```

Though.. if you have a shell available, it'd probably be a lot faster to do:
(Thanks to Amro for the improved last line)

```
head -n 2 raw_data.dat > angle_data.dat
tail -n 2 raw_data.dat >> angle_data.dat
head -n -2 raw_data.dat | tail -n +3 > final_data.dat
```

Comment: the last two lines could be simply: `head -n -2 raw_data.dat | tail -n +3 > final_data.dat`

Comment: Thanks--I thought there should be a way to do that, but didn't know it off the top of my head